# Does TFS 2010 or TFS 2012 offer full remote administration? It looks like it comes close, but not quite certain

Tags: tfs

I've been looking over TFS documentation and books for a specific instance where it is stated that full remote administration of TFS is possible.  It looks like some functionality is exposed through web services, but that seems to be mostly the same as that for users.  It also looks like TFS can be mirrored and copied to multiple places, so that *suggests* a type of remote administrative ability (or of remote configuration settings being copied).

There's even a TFS server administration tool available on Codeplex (http://tfsadmin.codeplex.com/releases/view/57795), but it looks kinda junky for TFS 2010, and I'm not 100% certain that it administers all the possible settings.  Could someone please verify for me with certainty if TFS has remote administration functionality or not?  Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: I believe I may have answered my own question.  In the book "Professional Team Foundation Server 2012" by Ed Blankenship et al in chapter 19 on page 498 it states: "Perhaps the biggest limitation of the tool (and most of the built-in admin tools) is that it must be run on the app tier servers themselves. Although you can use Remote Desktop and tools like PSExec.exeto connect to the server remotely, the tools must still execute locally on the server. After logging on to your app tier server, navigate to the Team Foundation Server Administration Console icon and the admin console will open."

Comment: This is correct. There is a lot of administration that can be done (mainly high level administration such as project/team/security/etc.) remotely; however, there are a few server-level commands that must be run on the app-tier. Are there specific administration tasks you are looking to achieve remotely?

Comment: The TFS Server Admin Tool from Codeplex is extremely weak.  Overall, administration of TFS is unnecessarily opaque and complex.  While it is true that many admin tasks can be done remotely via command line for instance, most TFS installations are too complex to reasonably manage that way.